# formula for multiple rows give answer for 1st row, but changes to corresponding row result when double cclicked + Enter

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So this is an odd duck of an issue. I'm using VLOOKUP to search for text for multiple rows, a routine task I preform every month without issue.

```
=VLOOKUP(C9072,'[GL MAPPING FOR PURCHASING & OTHERS.xls]COST PROFIT CENTER'!$J:$K,2,0)
```

But this time, when I use VLOOKUP the entire row has the text for the 1st row. Then, when I double-click on a random row below to see the issue, it changes text to its proper value when I press Enter.

This has never happened to me before, and I'm not sure what I did to cause this.

Edit:
This issue doesn't just apply to VLOOKUP as I did more tests. Normal mathematics formula is affected too. I did found a workaround though, where if I save my file, the correct values for all rows refreshes. Which is a relief, but still it's not normal...

Comment: Go to your user settings and change calculation type to automatic... probably the issue.